# Emoji vectors via spacy

Tags: spacy, emoji

In short, emoji vectors in spacy?  Where is this documented?

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

a = ""
b = "❄️"
v = ""
h = ""
l = ""
e = [a,b,v,h,l]

# emoji vector
ev = [nlp(emoji).vector for emoji in e]

# numpy array
ev = np.array(ev)

ev.shape
```

The shape is `(5, 96)`, so I am curious as to where I can learn more about the source of the vectors.  At first, I assumed that these were OOV, but:

`ev.sum(axis=1)`

yields

```
array([2.906692 , 3.8687153, 1.2295313, 3.986846 , 1.9255924],
      dtype=float32)
```

> All above is via Colab environment as of 2/21/2021

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sm` models do not contain word vectors. If there aren't any word vectors, `token.vector` returns `token.tensor` as a backoff, which is the context-sensitive tensor from the `tagger` component. See the first warning box here: https://v2.spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity

If you want word vectors, use an `md` or `lg` model instead, and then the emoji will be OOV and `token.vector` will return an all-0 300d vector.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  I haven't dug too deeply in the docs aside of quick scans for specific use cases.  Thanks for the link,